# Rails 7 has_secure_password doesn't throw validation error on update when password is blank

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm running Rails 7.0.4 right now.

Here's my User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: {with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP, message: "Please use a valid email address."},
                    uniqueness: true

end
```

Given a standard user,

When I update the password with blank information,

I expect a validation error "can't be blank" to get thrown.

What I get instead is no error thrown and what looks like a successful database transaction with no rollback.

Here's an example where I use the `update` method on an instance of User and see the validation doesn't get thrown and prevent the transaction.

```
 pry(main)> u = User.first
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User:0x0000000108e89280
 id: 1,
 fullname: "foo",
 email: "foo@bar.com",
 password_digest: "[FILTERED]",
 created_at: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 04:13:52.650976000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 04:13:52.672566000 UTC +00:00,
 company_id: nil,
 auth_token: "[FILTERED]">
[4] pry(main)> u.update(password: '', password_confirmation: '')
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "foo@bar.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

And here is the continuation of the above session where I attempt to just set the attributes and call `save` directly. This is what I understand the `update` and `update_attributes` methods do under the hood.

```
[5] pry(main)> u.password
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> attributes = { password: '', password_confirmation: '' }
=> {:password=>"", :password_confirmation=>""}
[7] pry(main)> u.attributes
=> {"id"=>1,
 "fullname"=>"foo",
 "email"=>"foo@bar.com",
 "password_digest"=>"$2a$12$W5CwTg.DjhLZdSiXDvD2fuWinwbMtmavK46IZCR27EzopLgfQzQxy",
 "created_at"=>Fri, 06 Jan 2023 04:13:52.650976000 UTC +00:00,
 "updated_at"=>Fri, 06 Jan 2023 04:13:52.672566000 UTC +00:00,
 "company_id"=>nil,
 "auth_token"=>
  "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6Ik1RPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InVzZXIvc2Vzc2lvbnMifX0=--239334c38fd5527b383c22d7aad6277f07743b3f6ecd2de846d42731c22e39d5"}
[8] pry(main)> u.attributes = attributes
=> {:password=>"", :password_confirmation=>""}
[9] pry(main)> u
=> #<User:0x0000000108e89280
 id: 1,
 fullname: "foo",
 email: "foo@bar.com",
 password_digest: "[FILTERED]",
 created_at: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 04:13:52.650976000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 04:13:52.672566000 UTC +00:00,
 company_id: nil,
 auth_token: "[FILTERED]">
[10] pry(main)> u.save
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "foo@bar.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Shouldn't `save` trigger the validation errors, which are in `has_secure_password`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the current sourcecode for the update method.

```
     def update(id, attributes)
        if id.is_a?(Array)
          idx = -1
          id.collect { |one_id| idx += 1; update(one_id, attributes[idx]) }
        else
          object = find(id)
          object.update_attributes(attributes)
          object
        end
      end
```

And that refers to the update_attributes method here:

```
      def update_attributes(attributes)
        self.attributes = attributes
        save
      end
```

And here's the has_secure_password sourcecode:

```
      def has_secure_password(options = {})
        # Load bcrypt gem only when has_secure_password is used.
        # This is to avoid ActiveModel (and by extension the entire framework)
        # being dependent on a binary library.
        begin
          require "bcrypt"
        rescue LoadError
          $stderr.puts "You don't have bcrypt installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
          raise
        end

        include InstanceMethodsOnActivation

        if options.fetch(:validations, true)
          include ActiveModel::Validations

          # This ensures the model has a password by checking whether the password_digest
          # is present, so that this works with both new and existing records. However,
          # when there is an error, the message is added to the password attribute instead
          # so that the error message will make sense to the end-user.
          validate do |record|
            record.errors.add(:password, :blank) unless record.password_digest.present?
          end

          validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED
          validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true
        end
      end
```

After studying the `has_secure_password` sourcecode I saw that it only throws the blank validation error when password_digest is blank.

So the solution here that I've found is to create a validation of my own in the model class to check for presence upon updates, and to  pass it my own message. I also see that this method doesn't check for password strength, so I needed to add in password strength regex.

Here is the new model class and it works as expected.

The downside is that this implementation doesn't pull apart the different parts of the regex that it doesn't fail. So if the password is missing a symbol it will just render the entire format validation error instead of specifically saying "Password must include a symbol."

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: {with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP, message: "be a valid email format"},
                    uniqueness: true

  PASSWORD_REQUIREMENTS = /\A
  (?=.{6,}) # At least 6 characters long
  (?=.*\d)
  (?=.*[a-z])
  (?=.*[A-Z])
  (?=.*[[:^alnum:]])
  /x

  validates :password, presence: true,
                       format: { with: PASSWORD_REQUIREMENTS,
                                 message: 'must be at least 6 characters long, contain a number, a lower and upper letter, and have one special character.' }


end
```